# Free mac-native subtitle editing

Tags: subtitles, mac

I sometimes need to generate lots of subtitles for a video file.

I've been using [Aegisub](http://www.aegisub.org/), but it hasn't been updated since 2014, and I'm wondering if there's a better alternative.

I export an .srt file from Aegisub, then import it into [PtImportSubtitles](https://aescripts.com/pt_importsubtitles/) in After Effects, to generate text keyframes.

This works well, but the software is old and looking like it won't be updated ever...

Is there anything better?

[Jubler](http://jubler.org) - looks clunky, needs Java runtime to operate

[SWXE](http://www.uruworks.net/description.html) - non-native mac app, menus don't appear to work properly under MacOS 10.14

Comment: Is there a positive problem with Aegisub?

Comment: It's not very intuitive, but I'm more worried that it's going to stop working when MacOS is next updated, as the software hasn't been kept updated for so long.  I'm wondering how others on the mac do this, and whether there's other software available that I don't know about.

Comment: [MacCaption](http://www.telestream.net/captioning/overview.htm)? Or are you specifically looking for open source?

Comment: Looking for something that doesn’t cost £1700